# JS The function work well in localhost, but not in live server

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I am using javascript in localhost and it works well,
but after I uploaded my script to my live server, it wouldn't run, why?

```
 <ul class="list-form-column">
                                <li>
                                    <label class="radio">
                                    <input id="radio11" type="radio" name="radio2" value="cod" checked>
                                    <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>COD</label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label class="radio">
                                    <input id="radio12" type="radio" name="radio2" value="paypal">
                                    <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>PAYPAL</label>
                                </li>
                            </ul>   
                            <form name="paymentForm" id="paymentForm" action="{{ url('/place-order-cod') }}" method="post"> {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <div class="payment-options">
                                <input type="hidden" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" value="{{ $grand_total }}">
                                    <span>
                                        <label><strong></strong></label>
                                    </span>
                                    <span style="align-items: center; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
                                        <input class="cod btn" type="submit" value="PLACE ORDER" style="width: 250px;">
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <form name="paymentForm" id="paymentForm" action="{{ url('/place-order') }}" method="post"> {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <div class="payment-options">
                                <input type="hidden" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" value="{{ $grand_total }}">
                                    <span>
                                        <label><strong></strong></label>
                                    </span>
                                    <span style="align-items: center; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
                                        <input name="submit" type="image" src="{{ asset('frontend/images/paypal.png') }}" class="paypal" style="display: none; margin-top: -45px">
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

above is my html code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=radio2]:radio').change(function(e) {
    var value = e.target.value.trim()

    $('[class^="paymentForm"]').css('display', 'none');

    switch (value) {
      case 'cod':
        $('.cod').show()
        $('.paypal').hide()
        break;
      case 'paypal':
        $('.paypal').show()
        $('.cod').hide()
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

this is the script code, that I put into main file. Please help, it works well in localhost. it shall hide the button and show another, but at live server it do nothing.

Comment: Is there any error message in the console? Like `jQuery cannot be loaded` or something like that?

Comment: No, it doesn't show any error in console

Comment: give me live url

Comment: Do you block scripts from being executed on the live server, either via a browser config or an extension? For a simple test just add a `alert("test");` before the ready function.

Comment: In other news: You have two forms with the same ID. Your code also searches for a class containing "paymentForm" but your HTML doesn't have a class with that name, only names and IDs.

Comment: should i add the class "paymentForm" inside the both form?